# How do I inspect my 3d model interactively?

Tags: interactive, renderer, 3d-modelling

I have an array of lines and other primitives. For example, it's a tree like this one:

[image]

Now I need to look an it from different angles and I want to be able to rotate it with my mouse. Is there any lightweight "player" (maybe online version) and what format should I use for it? What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

So I've converted a set of vertices and lines to a [Wavefront OBJ format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) and just drag'n'dropped to https://threejs.org/editor/

[image]